# How to insert data in a table with foreign keys?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Good evening guys, I hope you all are well. I'm from latin america, so I hope you excuse my writing.

I have a database with 3 tables:

1. tenant (the users)
2. company (the user's companies)
3. company_x_tenant (which is generated by the relation many-to-many that tenant and company have)

so `company_x_tenant` has foreign keys (that are the primary keys that company and tenant have).

I'm trying to insert data into `company_x_tenant` table, but it's not allowed until I insert data into the tenant table and then the company table.

The problem is that I don't know if when I insert data into the company table, I should make a second insert to the `company_x_tenant` table. My boss says that the `company_x_table` exists because the website needs to prevent every user from deleting any company, so just one user can have complete access to it's own companies and delete or update them.

I hope I made myself clear :( Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If only one user should be related to a company in this manner, there is no need for the company_x_tenant table; those are mostly for "many to many" relationships. Just put some "owner_user_id" field in the company table that is a foreign key to users.user_id.

Comment: I knew that i can do that, but my buss is the one who made the database and says that i need to use the company_x_tenant table, so my big question is if i have to make two inserts?

Comment: If every company must have a corresponding company_x_tenant record, then two inserts would always be required (though a trigger may be able to automatically do the second); and if an appropriate user does not exist, then technically another insert would be required for that (unless the user_id in company_x_tenant is NULLable). However, there is no way I know of to enforce every company having a company_x_tenant record.